# Diablo 3 RoS how to play with friend on 360?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I have Reaper of Souls for 360 and my friend only has the original release of Diablo 3. How can my friend and I play together?

Comment: Diablo 3 the original game?  For 360 as well?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. For all intents and purposes, *Diablo III* and *Diablo III: Ultimate Evil Edition* are separate games, even on the same platform, and cannot play multiplayer together.